# Can't trigger page load event in Selenium

Tags: selenium, event-handling, dom-events, eventtrigger, onload-event

In the snippet of code below I would expect the program to print `True`, but instead it prints `False`.  It appears that the event listener isn't being triggered, but I don't understand why.

```
from selenium import webdriver


javascript_code = f'''
    var x = false;
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {{
        x=true;
    }});

    window.location.href = "https://google.com";
    return x;
'''

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print(driver.execute_script(javascript_code))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
javascript_code = f'''
```

to

```
javascript_code = '''
```